Copy selected files in the file explorer
I want to copy selected pictures from in file explorer. It has to be the file explorer because i need to visualize the pictures before selecting them. I found this sub :
Sub DetermineTheSelectedFiles()
  'It needs `Microsoft Internet Controls`. Take care of adding this reference!
  Dim ExpWin As SHDocVw.ShellWindows, CurrWin As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
  Set ExpWin = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
  
   For Each CurrWin In ExpWin
        If Not CurrWin.Document Is Nothing Then
            If Not CurrWin.Document.FocusedItem Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print CurrWin.Document.FocusedItem.Path: Stop
            End If
        End If
    Next CurrWin
End Sub

Unfortunately, i get only the last selected picture.
Can you help me ?
Thanks in advance.
Daniel

I revised your code to get the selected file names;
Sub DetermineTheSelectedFiles()
  'It needs `Microsoft Internet Controls`. Take care of adding this reference!
  Dim ExpWin As SHDocVw.ShellWindows, CurrWin As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
  Dim objItems As Object, i As Integer
  
  Set ExpWin = New SHDocVw.ShellWindows
  
   For Each CurrWin In ExpWin
        If Not CurrWin.Document Is Nothing Then
            If Not CurrWin.Document.FocusedItem Is Nothing Then
                Set objItems = CurrWin.Document.SelectedItems
                For i = 0 To objItems.Count - 1
                    Debug.Print objItems.Item(CLng(i)).Name
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

.
If you need to get the full path name of the selected items, then use this;
Debug.Print objItems.Item(CLng(i)).Path
.
Note: Please upvote and accept the post as an Answer if your problem is solved.
